# RestEasy 3.0.9 Disable GZIP Interceptors

Tags: resteasy

s
    RESTEasy by default adds the GZIP compression and decompression through GZIPDecodingInterceptor and GZIPEncodingInterceptor interceptor. I trying to find out if its possible to disable these interceptors.

```
E.g. If I post a gzipped MultiPart, on the Server side I see that the file is decompressed. I'd like to keep the file compressed and used it in my integration flows.

As per the documentation, @Provider can be enabled disabled through the config below. But it did not work.

<context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

Appreciate answers..
```